# LINQ Group By with Replace

Tags: sql-server, linq

Suppose I have a table like:

```
ColumnA    ColumnB
-------    -------
Used       Citroen
Km0        BMW
New        BMW
Used       Peugeot
Used       Volvo
```

In LINQ I would extract all distinct values of COlumnA but in the result I would grouping 'Used' and 'Km0' under the same value:
so the result will be:

```
Used -> 4 cars
New -> 1 car
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have specific values that you would like to "bundle" with other items in a group, you could use a conditional expression for it:

```
var res = cars
    .GroupBy(c => c.ColumnA == "Km0" ? "Used" : c.ColumnA)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating an EqualityComparer that compares two ColumnA types for equality and returns true if one is `Used` and the other is `Km0`,

If you do this, you can use this for every linq statement where you want to tread `Km0` as `Used`, not only in GroupBy, but also in ToDictionary, Where, Distinct, etc

Assuming ColumnA is a string. Microsoft recommends deriving equality comparers from class [EqualityComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132123%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
class CarColumnAComparer : EqualityComparer<string>
{
    public static IEqualityComparer<string> Comparer
    {
        get{return new CarColumnAComparer();}
    }

    const string used = 'Used';
    const string km0 = "Km0";

    public override bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        if (x == null) return y == null; // true if both null, false ix x null, y not null
        if (y==null) return false;       // x is not null, false if y null
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y) return true;
        if (x.GetType() != y.GetType()) return false; // false if different types

        // declare equal if one is 'Used' and other is 'Km0'
        if (x == used && y == km0) return true;
        else if (x == km) and y == used) return true;
        else return x == y;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(string x)
    {
         if (x == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(x));

         // return the same hashCode for x==used and x==km0:
         if (x == km0)
             return used.GetHashCode();
         else
             return x.GetHashCode();
    }
```

Usage:

```
var result = cars.GroupBy(car => car.ColumnA, carColumnAComparer.Comparer);
```

or

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Car> CarDictionary(carColumnAComparer.Comparer);
var disinctValues = cars.Distinct(carColumnAComparer.Comparer);
```